# np.where, multiple and or statement, two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two different data frames (`nv1 and db1`). I want to create a new column in `nv1` named `Novel_in_Database` with value `"Yes"` or `"No"` based on multiple conditions.

The conditions are: The value of column `MinBP` of `nv1` is greater than the value of column `min_bp` of `db1` and smaller than `max_bp` of `db1`. Or The value of column `MaxBP` of `nv1` is greater than the value of `min_bp` of `db1` and smaller than `max_bp` of `db1`. Did I clarify the conditions?
Here are my data frames.

```
db1
min_bp  max_bp
11  22
20  30
38  52
```

And

```
nv1
    MinBP   MaxBP
    10  20
    15  25
    36  50
    60  80
    85  96
```

The new nv1 would be:

```
MinBP   MaxBP   Novel_in_Database
10  20  No
15  25  No
36  50  Yes
60  80  Yes
85  96  Yes
```

So far, I have tried as follows,

```
nv1['Novel_in_Database']=np.where((((nv1.MinBP >= db1.min_bp) & (nv1.MinBP <= db1.max_bp)) |
                                   ((nv1.MaxBP <= db1.max_bp) & (nv1.MaxBP >= db1.min_bp))), 'No', 'Yes')
```

But it is giving me error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`. These two data frames are of different shapes. Any help?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to compare two Series of different lengths? Which values _should_ be compared?

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question with example data. The `MinBP/MaxBP` of `nv1` needs to be in between `min_bp` and `max_bp` of `db1`. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Are you finding out that a range in `nv1` overlaps *any* range from `db1`? If so I don't understand why the first row of the result is "No". `(10, 20)` clearly overlaps `(11, 22)`

Comment: @CodeDifferent, IIUC I think if overlaps, the row already exists in database so the value should be 'no'. Check the condition of `np.where`: if True return 'no' else 'yes'.

Comment: @Corralien then why does the third row returns Yes? It overlaps and by your logic it should be No

Comment: @CodeDifferent. I think there is an error to the expected outcome :-P or I have a problem of logic. lol.

Comment: @CodeDifferent and `@Corralien`, yes, there was an error to the expect outcome. The MinBP/MaxBP of nv1 needs to be in between min_bp and max_bp of db1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `merge` with `how='cross'` to create a new dataframe that contains all combinations of `(nv1, db1)`:

```
df = pd.merge(nv1.reset_index(), db1, how='cross')
```

Here is the output:

```
>>> df
    index  MinBP  MaxBP  min_bp  max_bp
0       0     10     20      11      22
1       0     10     20      20      30
2       0     10     20      38      52
3       1     15     25      11      22
4       1     15     25      20      30
5       1     15     25      38      52
6       2     36     50      11      22
7       2     36     50      20      30
8       2     36     50      38      52
9       3     60     80      11      22
10      3     60     80      20      30
11      3     60     80      38      52
12      4     85     96      11      22
13      4     85     96      20      30
14      4     85     96      38      52
```

Now check your conditions:

```
df['Novel_in_Database'] = df['MinBP'].between(df['min_bp'], df['max_bp']) \
                        | df['MaxBP'].between(df['min_bp'], df['max_bp'])
```

For each group from `nv1`, find all new rows:

```
nv1['Novel_in_Database'] = (~df.groupby('index')['Novel_in_Database'].any()) \
                           .replace({True: 'yes', False: 'no'})
```

```
>>> nv1
   MinBP  MaxBP Novel_in_Database
0     10     20                no
1     15     25                no
2     36     50                no
3     60     80               yes
4     85     96               yes
```

Comment: Neat! Now I get the question ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's array broadcasting to all elements in an array against all elements in another array:

```py
a = nv1['MinBP'].to_numpy()
b = nv1['MaxBP'].to_numpy()

# Raise the columns in db1 by a dimension to enable numpy's broadcasting
c = db1['min_bp'].to_numpy()[:, None]
d = db1['max_bp'].to_numpy()[:, None]

result = ((a > c) & (a < d)) | ((b > c) & (b < d))
nv1['Novel_in_Database'] = np.where(result.any(axis=0), 'No', 'Yes')
```